# How do I end a looping script in crontab?

Tags: linux, github, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a script that runs through a never ending loop. Using cron I start the script on reboot. However, I need to update this script from github every 24 hours. I'm running a shell script that basically follows:

1. Backup cron to .txt file
2. Empty cron with crontab -r
3. Pull updates from GitHub
4. Load cron backup and start cron again.

The shell script empties cron, updates the code, then starts cron again with the same file name and cron runs the program again. I'm testing this by outputting a message to a text file every time the script completes one loop. When I change the message output in GitHub, cron pulls the update and I can see the updated message. The problem is, it continues to show the old message as well. For example:

Original Message "Test": Test Test Test Test Test Test
Updated Message "Update": Test Update Test Update Test Update

It continues to output old messages even though I cleared cron, updated the code, then started it again. It appears to me that simply emptying cron does not stop the previous loop from continuing to run.

I looked into using "killall" to stop all sh scripts from running, but in an attempt to clear out the many looping scripts I had created I killed every running process with killall5 -9. Now when I enter ps to view running processes, none are listed.

I'm very stuck. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, in that your "emptying" and restoring crontabs, it seem you don't understand the typical work flow. Did you read the [crontab-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) ? Maybe you should get your project working on one machine, running one script at a time until you have better control over things. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Used sudo pkill python to end all running python scripts.

Comment: Glad that works for you, but assume that eventually this will kill scripts you don't want killed. Better solutions exist. All of them have trade offs. I think I would go with saving the "current PID" value to a "well-known" tmp file, and having an extra crontab entry that runs X (3?) minutes before you want to cycle things. All that script would have to do would be read the well-known PID file value, and kill just that process tree. Then the main script can start up. It is possible to have just the main script do all of this too. Good luck.